# Extrar variable de PHP a android

Tags: php, android, json

Tengo los siguientes codigos de un proyecto android que estoy desarrollando hasta el momento mi archivo `wsJSONConsultarLista.php` me muestra toda la informacion solicitada, pero no encuentro la manera de extraer la variable `$dias` a mi aplicacion android y aplicar la logica `IF/ELSEIF` en mi android dependiendo del resultado de la variable `$dias`

wsJSONConsultarLista.php

```
<?php

    require "conexion.php";
    
    // PRUEBAS
    //$usuario = "cheko";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados,certificaciones WHERE empleado_id = codigo_persona AND Puesto = 'MONTACARGUISTA' AND Certificacion IN ('Montacargas', 'Picker')";
    //$consulta="select reloj,nombre,area,equipo,fecha_ent,Certificacion,Fecha_Cert,Fecha_Ven,empleado_id from tb_registro,certificaciones WHERE empleado_id = reloj AND Certificacion IN ('Montacargas', 'Picker')";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    $datos = array();

    $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    
    while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $datos[] = $resultado;

        $fecha_final = new DateTime($resultado['Fecha_Ven']);
        $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');
        // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
        if ($dias <=0) {
           echo '<td align=center ><font color="#FF0000">Certificacion Vencida</font></td>';
        }
        elseif($dias <= 15) {
           echo '<td align=center ><Font color="#FF8C00"> Está a ' . $dias . ' días de vencer </FONT></td>';
        }
        if ($dias >=16){
           echo '<td align=center ><font color="#3CB371">Certificacion Vigente</font></td>';
        }   
           echo "</tr>";
    }
    
    //echo json_encode($datos);
    echo json_encode(array("Usuarios" => $datos));
?>
```

clase android homefragment.java

```
    public void obtenerUsuarios() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.URL_USUARIOS),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Usuarios");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                listaUsuarios.add(
                                        new Asociados(
                                                jsonObject1.getString("codigo_persona"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("Nombre"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("Puesto"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("Departamento"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("Fecha_Ven"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("Imagen")));
                            }

                            adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(AsociadosActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
                            rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

   requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Asociados.java

```
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Asociados implements Serializable {

    String codigo_persona;
    String Nombre;
    String Puesto;
    String Departamento;
    String vencimiento;
    String image;
    String msg;


    public Asociados(String codigo_persona, String Nombre, String Puesto, String Departamento, String vencimiento, String Image, String msg) {
        this.codigo_persona = codigo_persona;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Puesto = Puesto;
        this.Departamento = Departamento;
        this.image = Image;
        this.vencimiento = vencimiento;
        this.msg = msg;

    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getIdUsuario() {
        return codigo_persona;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(String codigo_persona) {
        this.codigo_persona = codigo_persona;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {

        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {

        return Puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String Puesto) {

        this.Puesto = Puesto;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {

        return Departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String Departamento) {

        this.Departamento = Departamento;
    }

    public String getVencimiento(){
        return vencimiento;
    }

    public void setVencimiento(String vencimiento){
        this.vencimiento = vencimiento;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

Les agradeceria si pudieran orientarme de como deberia extraer la variable `$dias` a mi aplicacion android para poder implementar las condiciones `IF/ELSEIF`.

Mi aplicacion se ve asi con el codigo .php actual pero si le quito el metodo para calcular las diferencias ya me muestra los datos.

`**ACLARO EL PROYECTO NO ME MUESTRA O ARROJA NINGUN ERROR AL CORRER SOLO ME MUESTRA LA LISTA EN BLANCO**`

Con codigo para calcular dias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin codigo para calcular dias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el código de `wsJSONConsultarLista.php`? ¿Para qué es `json.php` y dónde lo usas exactamente? ¿Qué has depurado y con qué resultados?

Comment: Ya corregi la pregunta el archivo json es el mismo que wsJsonconsultarlista

Lo que hace es extraer mis datos que tengo en mi tabla tb_registro y lo que quiero hacer es poder aplicar en mi proyecto android el siguiente codigo que se encuentra en mi clase search.php de un proyecto web que me calcula la diferencia de dias entre 2 fechas 

`$fecha_final = new DateTime($row['Fecha_Ven']);
$dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');`

Y poder aplicar la logica de `if` en mi aplicacion android

Comment: En Android tú estás llamando a `wsJSONConsultarLista.php`, ahora bien, depura tu código, poniendo puntos de interrupción y verificando los objetos en esos puntos o usando `Log.d` y dinos qué has observado en la depuración después de revisar el Logcat, pues no sabemos si la petición falla, o si devuelve algo, o qué devuelve.

Comment: Mira mi `wsJSONConsultarLista.php` si me devuelve mis datos bien me los muestra en mi recyclerview ahora lo que yo quiero es implementar lo de calcular los dias y el resultado de la diferencia mandarlo a llamar y mostrarlo junto con los otros datos que me muestra mi pregunta en si es como puedo implementar lo que tengo en mi proyecto web a mi aplicacion android

Comment: Es que no entiendo. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente y dónde? ¿Qué has depurado y con qué resultados?

Comment: Mira ya intente implementarlo yo y lo unico que me muestra es que la conexion al json falla por lo cual no me muestra la informacion.

Por lo que les estoy pidiendo apoyo para saber como aplicar `$fecha_final = new DateTime($row['Fecha_Ven']); $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');` esto a mi proyecto android ya que la variable `$dias` no se como llamarla devuelta a mi aplicacion android ya que no la tengo almacenada en la `BD`

Comment: Tú tienes que crear un array y mandarlo a Android usando `json_encode`, quitando los `echo` que tienes, pues es normal que si Android espera un JSON y tú haces `echo` de otras cosas, como `td`, cadenas, etc, recibirás un JSON no válido en Android. Sea como sea, pon siempre en la pregunta el error exacto que da el código indicando dónde falla. Eso es esencial para ayudarte a avanzar en la resolución del problema.

Comment: Yo ya tengo un array es el siguiente que esta en `wsJSONConsultarLista.php` ahi es donde quiero implementar el de `$fecha_final = new DateTime($row['Fecha_Ven']); $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');`. Lo que habia echo era crear un 2do array en el cual se llamara la variable `$dias` pero cuando lo hice la app me mostro el mensaje de que no se conseguia conectar con el json debido a que tenia 2 array.

Comment: Prueba a modificar la parte del `while` así: `while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ $json[]=$registro; }`  y luego: **`echo json_encode(array('usuario'=>$json));`** De todos modos, aún no entiendo cómo entra tu primer bloque de código en esto esto. Es evidente que tienes problemas para explicar el problema, y ese es el mayor problema.

Comment: Mira deja edito toda la pregunta haber si me explico mejor

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya modifique la pregunta haber si quedo un poco mas claro lo que estoy intenta hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de los `echo` que tienes en cada `if`, debes poner una propiedad en el array, y lo tendrás así en Android cuando recibas la respuesta.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    require "conexion.php";
    
    // PRUEBAS
    //$usuario = "cheko";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados,certificaciones WHERE empleado_id = codigo_persona AND Puesto = 'MONTACARGUISTA' AND Certificacion IN ('Montacargas', 'Picker')";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    $datos = array();

    $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    
    while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $msg="";
        $fecha_final = new DateTime($resultado['Fecha_Ven']);
        $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');
        // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
        if ($dias <=0) {
           $msg="Certificacion Vencida";
        }
        elseif($dias <= 15) {
           $msg="Está a $dias días de vencer";
        }
        else {
           $msg="Certificacion Vigente";
        }
        /*
           Ponemos en $resultado una clave msg
           y en ella el valor de la variable $msg
           En Android, podrás obtener ese valor invocando a msg
           y puedes cambiar msg por como se llame
           el campo destinado a ese dato en tu clase Asociados
        */
        $resultado['msg']=$msg;
        $datos[] = $resultado;   
    }
    
    echo json_encode(array("Usuarios" => $datos));
?>
```

Aquí hemos recogido en la variable `$msg` el mensaje, y luego hemos agregado ese valor en `$registro` bajo una clave `msg`, así en Android, en la clave `msg` de cada fila tendrás el valor resultante. Puedes cambiar el nombre de la clave `msg` por la propiedad respectiva en tu clase `Asociados` de Android. Dado que no queda claro cómo se llama esa propiedad, no lo he hecho.

Además de eso, es importante que quites los `echo`, los cuales producirían un JSON no válido.

Por otra parte, tampoco estabas usando bien el `if / elseif` en tu código PHP.

Así debería funcionar. Si tienes alguna duda, pregunta en comentarios debajo de esta respuesta.

Comment: Okey deja lo intento como me dices y te comento si me funciono
mcuhas gracias disculpa que te confundiera tanto

Comment: Me podrias ayudar creo que declare mal mi variable msg en mi clase Asociados primero la declare como una variable Message pero al llamarla en la clase `homefragment.java` solo me acepta `.getString` asi que la volvi String pero no me muestra ningun mensaje, solo los demas datos. ya añadi el codigo de la clase asociados a la pregunta o si hay alguna otra manera de mostrar el resultado sin que sea en un mensaje por ejemplo poder ponerlo en un EditText claro si es mas sencillo

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude llamar la variable `msg` a un edittext muchas gracias amigo